# Python Pandas: Fill dataframe with the same category name (in one column) and NaN (in another)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this (but much larger):

```
       year city_code  total_tax
id_inf                           
9       2002       NaN        NaN
9       2003         a      417.0
9       2004         a      950.0
9       2005       NaN        NaN
9       2006       NaN        NaN
54      2002         b      801.0
54      2003       NaN        NaN
54      2004         b      218.0
54      2005         b      886.0
54      2006         b      855.0
```

I need to fill 'city_code' with the same category of 'id_inf' and replace NaN with zeros in column 'total_tax'.

The second task is quite easy: `df_balanced['total_tax'] = df_balanced['total_tax'].fillna(0)`

But for the first task I was suggested to use something similar to: 'df_balanced['city_code'] = df_balanced.groupby(level=0)['city_code'].transform(max)'. However, when I use this solution, I'm getting this mistake: `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`

The output I need is something like this:

```
        year city_code  total_tax
id_inf                           
9       2002         a        0.0
9       2003         a      417.0
9       2004         a      950.0
9       2005         a        0.0
9       2006         a        0.0
54      2002         b      801.0
54      2003         b        0.0
54      2004         b      218.0
54      2005         b      886.0
54      2006         b      855.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `first`

```
df['city_code']=df.groupby('id_inf').city_code.transform('first')
#df.groupby('id_inf').city_code.transform('first')
Out[278]: 
id_inf
9     a
9     a
9     a
9     a
9     a
54    b
54    b
54    b
54    b
54    b
Name: city_code, dtype: object
```